# python. relative path inside a module with libpath

Tags: python, pathlib

I am creating a module as follows:
[image]

the codes lives in src/phonebook/book.py

inside book.py there is a class

that class has to read data from DATA folder into a pandas dataframe.

What is the way to mount the relative path?

```
DATA_ROOT = Path('..').parents[2]
print(DATA_ROOT)
CSV_USERS_PATH = DATA_ROOT / Path('DATA')
```

nor with:

```
DATA_ROOT = Path('__file__').parents[2]
print(DATA_ROOT)
CSV_USERS_PATH = DATA_ROOT / Path('DATA')
```

so basically how can I code inside the class the Path to the DATA folder?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to point to the right path in a similar directory structure

```
CSV_USERS_PATH = Path(__file__).parents[2].joinpath('DATA')
```

Where it's assumed that this will be defined in `src/phonebook/book.py`

I think the missing pieces here were

- unnecessary quotes around `__file__`
- not using `joinpath()` to build the path